# Bootstrap 3 grid system basic understanding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have always worked under the Zurb's foundation logic for my grid systems. Now I'm trying bootstrap for first time in it's 3.0.2 version. One thing I don't understand is the structure of it.

While Zurb works like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has a 3-step structure to get the very same result:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My question is, what is the "row" class standing for?, on css it only sets a couple of margins and also clear the layout with the pseudo `:after` element. Can someone please explain me the logic of this? I'm sure that row is there because of a reason, but I can't find it.

Comment: All the .row really does is make sure that all of the div's inside of it appear on their own line, separated from the previous and the following .rows

Comment: You've nested things incorrectly - it should be `.row` -> `.container` -> `.col-*-*`

Comment: Correction @Bojangles, it should be:  .container ->.row -> .col-*-*

Comment: @Bojangleso that's the way it's nested?

Comment: So row goes actually within container @andre3wap ? I still don't understand why it takes 3 steps to do the same thing than foundation (even knowing that they're different workframes with their own rules)

Comment: @andre3wap Crap! That's what I mean, thank you

Comment: yes, the .container should be the upper level. then you have the .row, then the .col. I think the purpose of the .container is to enable 'responsiveness' in your design, which is the extra step over Foundation. @Bojangles, no problem bruh.

Comment: Is it possible to use the container and the cols directly @andre3wap? Or that would be a bad thing to do.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. However, you must take into account that later on down the line, you might add more html stuff, that's when the .rows will come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

`.container` only exists to give your layout a fixed-width (which is altered based on the end-user [responsive]). This class should also really only exist once on the page, and wrap all `.row` elements within (therefore living up to it's name--a container).

Bootstrap uses a fixed 12-column layout, and therefore only needs two pieces of information: `.row` to queue a new row, and one of the `col-*-n` classes to decipher how many columns that block should take up.

Columns are also broken down by three main layouts: `lg`, `md` and `sm` each having a different effect on the layout based on the window viewport. Bacause of these three variations, it's possible to specify that content should change based on browser capabilities (e.g display three columns on all devides (`md` & `lg`), but maybe switch to two on mobile (`sm`)).

Having said that, the most basic layout consists simply of:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    single div consuming all 12 columns
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then for example I just write down the container within header and close it on the footer and that way I don't have to repeat it permanently, correct?

Comment: BS3 rows have a negative margin. According to the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) "Rows must be placed within a .container for proper alignment and padding."

Comment: Yes @Skelly that's true, I read that on that page and saw the negative margins within style.

Comment: Exactly. As a result you get a horizontal scrollbar if you put the `row` directly in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I have basic knowledge of TWBS3 and this i how I understand it:

Imagine that your page is a table where, by default, you have 12 columns(this if you haven’t customized the configuration). When you have an element that has a class “col-*-*”, you will only use the space that is defined by the col class. Building on this, if you have 4 elements with  col-lg-4 class, you will get 3 elements  in line, whereas the fourth will be drawn in a second line. This is because 3 col-lg-4 elements add up to twelve columns, so the fourth element is pushed below the other elements. This might be good in some cases where the elements all have the same height(always), but when the height varies you get odd results  where some elements that are of smaller height are drawn a little higher in the page. ROW  enforces the idea of having   elements that belong to a row. Something like having a 12 column n rows table. Ex:

ELEMENT 1      ELEMENT2     ELEMENT 3

---

ELEMENT 4

With the same 4 elements of col-lg-4 you could do something like:

```
<div class=”row>
<div class=”col-lg-4”>Element 1</div><div class=”col-lg-4”>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class=”row>
<div class=”col-lg-4”>Element 3</div><div class=”col-lg-4”>Element 4</div>
</div>
```

ELEMENT 1      ELEMENT2

---

ELEMENT 3      ELEMENT 4

Because you are  saying that you have two rows, each with two elements, that span 4 rows, out of the twelve that you have available for the row.

Hope this helps you. Sorry about the bad english.